# How can I display all records including those with null values in manager_id using conditions?

Tags: sql, null, self-join

How can I display all records including those with null values in manager_id using conditions?

[image]

```
select e.last_name as Employee, e.employee_id as Emp#, d.last_name as Manager, d.employee_id as Mngr#
from hr.employees e, hr.employees d
where e.manager_id = d.employee_id
and e.manager_id is null;
```

Comment: Please update your question, with editable text, to 1) Explain what the issue is/what you are trying to achieve 2) Include the table definitions 3) Include sample data for these tables 4) Include the result you want to achieve with this sample data. Also, please learn to use ANSI SQL join syntax; the join syntax you are using hasn't been considered good practice for over 30 years

Comment: Change 'and' to 'or' in the where condition.
'where e.manager_id = d.employee_id
or e.manager_id is null;'

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is

```
enter image description here
select e.last_name as Employee, e.employee_id as Emp#, d.last_name as Manager, d.employee_id as Mngr#
from hr.employees e left join hr.employees d
on e.manager_id = d.employee_id;
```